# WSO2 Identity Server can not add user with more than one claim value through the API

Tags: exception, wso2, apache-axis, user-management, wso2-identity-server

I'm trying to add user account in WSO2 identity Server with UserStoreManager. I have no problems adding users with one claim value or without, but when i try to add more than one claim value in the claims' map it throws me an exception:

```
org.wso2.carbon.um.ws.api.WSUserStoreManager handleException 
SEVERE: Can not access the directory context oruser already exists in the system
org.apache.axis2.AxisFault: Can not access the directory context oruser already exists in the system..
```

This is the code i use

```
Map<String, String> claims = new HashMap<String, String>();
claims.put("http://wso2.org/claims/givenname", "John");
//second value causing the exception
claims.put("http://wso2.org/claims/lastname", "Doe");
STORE_MANAGER.addUser("JohnDoe", "123456",
      new String[] { Constants.DEFAULT_ROLE }, claims, "default");
```

Answer (score 1):

What is the IS version that your using ?

BTW Please try this

```
Map<String, String> claims = new HashMap<String, String>();

claims.put("http://wso2.org/claims/givenname", "John");

claims.put("http://wso2.org/claims/lastname", "Doe");

remoteUserStoreManager.addUser("JohnDoe", "123456",null, claims, "default");
```